# Is it possible to bridge a DSL connection via WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am using a PPPoE connection which is defined in my ADSL WiFi modem/router and I connect to the internet from my PC with a RJ45 cable via DHCP.

I have recently bought a Sony Bravia Smart TV, it's kept in my living room and it's not possible to connect the TV to my ADSL modem/router with an ethernet cable. There is an option of using a wifi dongle however these TVs only support Sony certified dongles. The dongles are expensive, so I was wondering whether it is possible to interface two wireless routers using wifi.

Something like, I keep my ADSL modem/router as it is in my bedroom. I get another wireless router and keep it next to my TV, configure the router to use the PPPoE connection defined in my adsl modem/router and then connect the router to my TV using a RJ45 cable.

Is it possible ? If yes then how ?

Cheers,

Utsav

Comment: configure router to connect to pppoe itself, get other wifi router, make it client or ap, and connect router to tv using rj45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the TV have an ethernet port?

IF so, instead of messing around, get a pair of Home Plug devices. These plug into your wall power sockets and make an ethernet connection. They are now pretty cheap, in the UK, you can get a pair of high speed (nominally 200MB though you'll never actually get that rate) ones for around £30-40. Put the first device close to the TV and the second close to the router. The first plugs into the TV's ethernet and the second into the router. Job done.

The alternative would be to get a WiFi extender/bridge, both TP-Link and Edimax do excellent, cheap ones. This would let you extend plug the TV's ethernet to the extender and then use the extender to bridge to your WiFi router.